# Need to filter out Kafka Records based on a certain keyword

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, lenses

I have a Kafka topic which has around 3 million records. I want to pick-out a single record from this which has a certain parameter. I have been trying to query this using Lenses, but unable to form the correct query. below are the record contents of 1 message.

```
{
  "header": {
    "schemaVersionNo": "1",
  },
  "payload": {
    "modifiedDate": 1552334325212,
    "createdDate": 1552334325212,
    "createdBy": "A",
    "successful": true,
    "source_order_id": "1111111111111",
  }
}
```

Now I want to filter out a record with a particular source_order_id, but not able to figure out the right way to do so.
We have tried via lenses as well Kafka Tool.

A sample query that we tried in lenses is below:

```
SELECT * FROM `TEST`
WHERE _vtype='JSON' AND _ktype='BYTES'
AND _sample=2 AND _sampleWindow=200 AND payload.createdBy='A'
```

This query works, however if we try with source id as shown below we get an error:

```
SELECT * FROM `TEST`
WHERE _vtype='JSON' AND _ktype='BYTES'
AND _sample=2 AND _sampleWindow=200 AND payload.source_order_id='1111111111111'



 Error : "Invalid syntax at line=3 and column=41.Invalid syntax for 'payload.source_order_id'. Field 'payload' resolves to primitive type STRING.
```

Consuming all 3 million records via a custom consumer and then iterating over it doesn't seem to be an optimised approach to me, so looking for any available solutions for such a use case.

Comment: What's `Apacha Lenses`? Do you mean Lenses and their Lenses SQL language?

Comment: Does the solution you're building have to be around Lenses? I can give you an answer based on KSQL if that's useful to you.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt: https://docs.lenses.io/overview/lenses-kafka.html

Comment: @RobinMoffatt: Not necessarily, any solution is fine .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you said you are open to other solutions, here is one built using [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/ksql).

First, let's get some sample records into a source topic:

```
$ kafkacat -P -b localhost:9092 -t TEST <<EOF
{ "header": { "schemaVersionNo": "1" }, "payload": { "modifiedDate": 1552334325212, "createdDate": 1552334325212, "createdBy": "A", "successful": true, "source_order_id": "3411976933214" } }
{ "header": { "schemaVersionNo": "1" }, "payload": { "modifiedDate": 1552334325412, "createdDate": 1552334325412, "createdBy": "B", "successful": true, "source_order_id": "3411976933215" } }
{ "header": { "schemaVersionNo": "1" }, "payload": { "modifiedDate": 1552334325612, "createdDate": 1552334325612, "createdBy": "C", "successful": true, "source_order_id": "3411976933216" } }
EOF
```

Using KSQL we can inspect the topic with `PRINT`:

```
ksql> PRINT 'TEST' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1552476232988,"ROWKEY":"null","header":{"schemaVersionNo":"1"},"payload":{"modifiedDate":1552334325212,"createdDate":1552334325212,"createdBy":"A","successful":true,"source_order_id":"3411976933214"}}
{"ROWTIME":1552476232988,"ROWKEY":"null","header":{"schemaVersionNo":"1"},"payload":{"modifiedDate":1552334325412,"createdDate":1552334325412,"createdBy":"B","successful":true,"source_order_id":"3411976933215"}}
{"ROWTIME":1552476232988,"ROWKEY":"null","header":{"schemaVersionNo":"1"},"payload":{"modifiedDate":1552334325612,"createdDate":1552334325612,"createdBy":"C","successful":true,"source_order_id":"3411976933216"}}
```

Then declare a schema on the topic, which enables us to run SQL against it:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM TEST (header STRUCT<schemaVersionNo VARCHAR>, 
                          payload STRUCT<modifiedDate BIGINT, 
                                        createdDate BIGINT, 
                                        createdBy VARCHAR, 
                                        successful BOOLEAN, 
                                        source_order_id VARCHAR>) 
                          WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TEST', 
                                VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

Message
----------------
Stream created
----------------
```

Tell KSQL to work with all the data in the topic:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.
```

And now we can select all the data:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM TEST;
1552475910106 | null | {SCHEMAVERSIONNO=1} | {MODIFIEDDATE=1552334325212, CREATEDDATE=1552334325212, CREATEDBY=A, SUCCESSFUL=true, SOURCE_ORDER_ID=3411976933214}
1552475910106 | null | {SCHEMAVERSIONNO=1} | {MODIFIEDDATE=1552334325412, CREATEDDATE=1552334325412, CREATEDBY=B, SUCCESSFUL=true, SOURCE_ORDER_ID=3411976933215}
1552475910106 | null | {SCHEMAVERSIONNO=1} | {MODIFIEDDATE=1552334325612, CREATEDDATE=1552334325612, CREATEDBY=C, SUCCESSFUL=true, SOURCE_ORDER_ID=3411976933216}
^CQuery terminated
```

or we can selectively query it, using the `->` notation to access nested fields in the schema:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM TEST 
        WHERE PAYLOAD->CREATEDBY='A';
1552475910106 | null | {SCHEMAVERSIONNO=1} | {MODIFIEDDATE=1552334325212, CREATEDDATE=1552334325212, CREATEDBY=A, SUCCESSFUL=true, SOURCE_ORDER_ID=3411976933214}
```

As well as selecting all records, you can return just the fields of interest:

```
ksql> SELECT payload FROM TEST 
        WHERE PAYLOAD->source_order_id='3411976933216';
{MODIFIEDDATE=1552334325612, CREATEDDATE=1552334325612, CREATEDBY=C, SUCCESSFUL=true, SOURCE_ORDER_ID=3411976933216}
```

With KSQL you can write the results of any `SELECT` statement to a new topic, which populates it with all existing messages along with every new message on the source topic filtered and processed per the declared `SELECT` statement:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM TEST_CREATED_BY_A AS
        SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE PAYLOAD->CREATEDBY='A';

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
```

List topic on the Kafka cluster:

```
ksql> SHOW TOPICS;

Kafka Topic            | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
orders                 | true       | 1          | 1                  | 1         | 1
pageviews              | false      | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
products               | true       | 1          | 1                  | 1         | 1
TEST                   | true       | 1          | 1                  | 1         | 1
TEST_CREATED_BY_A      | true       | 4          | 1                  | 0         | 0
```

Print the contents of the new topic:

```
ksql> PRINT 'TEST_CREATED_BY_A' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1552475910106,"ROWKEY":"null","HEADER":{"SCHEMAVERSIONNO":"1"},"PAYLOAD":{"MODIFIEDDATE":1552334325212,"CREATEDDATE":1552334325212,"CREATEDBY":"A","SUCCESSFUL":true,"SOURCE_ORDER_ID":"3411976933214"}}
```